# My x and y variables only sometimes change

Tags: java, variables, lwjgl

I am testing out a Player object in a game I am trying to build, and I have begun testing my input using a white rectangle on the screen through OpenGL in LWJGL.

The problem is that when I compile the code and try moving the rectangle using the arrow keys, the rectangle only responds to RIGHT and DOWN. When testing it out in the loop, it appears the dx and dy are changing in the move() method, but the change does not persist into the updateXY() method.

-SNIP- (jump problem has been fixed)

I am completely stumped as to why this could be and I would love to get some help

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Added the AbstractMoveableEntity class
EDIT: Updated the code to reflect the current problem

```
public class Player extends AbstractMoveableEntity implements MoveableEntity {

MouseHandler m;
private double tx, ty;
private double SPEED;

private enum DIR{
    UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
}

public Player(double x, double y, MouseHandler m) {
    super(x, y, 50, 50);
    this.m = m;
    this.tx = x;
    this.ty = y;
    this.ax = 0;
    this.ay = 0;
    this.SPEED = 5;
}

public void draw() {

    glRectd(x,y,x+width,y+height);

}

public void update(int delta) {

    updateXY();
    draw();

}

public void updateXY(){

    input();

    //Updating target, velocity and position values
    this.tx += this.dx;
    this.ty += this.dy;
    this.dx += this.ax;
    this.dy += this.ay;
    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;


    //Acceleration handling
    if(tx > x){
        this.ax += 1;
    } else if(tx < x) {
        this.ax -= 1;
    } else {
        this.ax = 0;
    }

    if(ty > y){
        this.ay += 1;
    } else if(ty < y) {
        this.ay -= 1;
    } else {
        this.ay = 0;
    }

}

public void input(){

    //Event-Driven input
    while(Keyboard.next()){
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)){
            if(ay == 0){
                jump();
            } else {
                x = tx;
                y = ty;
                ay = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    //Polled input
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)){
        move(DIR.UP);
    } else {
        stop(DIR.UP);
    }

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)){
        move(DIR.DOWN);
    } else {
        stop(DIR.DOWN);
    }

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)){
        move(DIR.LEFT);
    } else {
        stop(DIR.LEFT);
    }

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT)){
        move(DIR.RIGHT);
    } else {
        stop(DIR.RIGHT);
    }



}

public void jump(){
    setAY(-10);
    System.out.println("JUMP " + ay);
}

public void move(DIR d){

    if(d == DIR.UP){
        this.dy = -SPEED;
    } else if(d == DIR.DOWN){
        this.dy = SPEED;
    } else if(d == DIR.LEFT){
        this.dx = -SPEED;
    } else{
        this.dx = SPEED;
    }

}

public void stop(DIR d){

    if(d == DIR.UP || d == DIR.DOWN){
        this.dy = 0;
    } else {
        this.dx = 0;
    }

}
```

}

```
Public abstract class AbstractMoveableEntity extends AbstractEntity implements MoveableEntity {

protected double dx, dy, ax, ay;

public AbstractMoveableEntity(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
    super(x, y, width, height);
    this.dx = 0;
    this.dy = 0;
    this.ax = 0;
    this.ay = 0;
}

public double getDX() {
    return dx;
}

public double getDY() {
    return dy;
}

public void setDX(double dx) {
    this.dx = dx;
}

public void setDY(double dy) {
    this.dy = dy;
}

public void setAX(double ax){
    this.ax = ax;
}

public void setAY(double ay) {
    this.ay = ay;
}
```

}

Comment: It could be there's another variable declared as ax and ay, for your updateXY() method, use this.ax and this.ay instead. Also, I don't see where you declare your ax and ay variables.

Comment: `dx`, `dy`, `ax` and `ay` seem to be declared in the base class, could you add the declarations to the question? Also, are they updated anywhere in the base class?

Comment: I set everything to this.variable to make sure... Doesn't change anything. Here's the declaration and constructor for the class that Player extends:

`protected double dx, dy, ax, ay;
 
 public AbstractMoveableEntity(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
  super(x, y, width, height);
  this.dx = 0;
  this.dy = 0;
  this.ax = 0;
  this.ay = 0;
 }`

Sorry about the messy look, not sure how to fix

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on `if(tx > x){` and `if(ty > y){` and check the value of tx and x, and ty and y respectively. I'm suspecting it doesn't hit these conditions as declared in your Player object, `this.tx = x;` `this.ty = y;` That means the condition will never hit any of that to change your ax and ay variable as it will always be equal from the way you initialized the value and it never get changed. Seems to me you should use dx and dy instead of tx and ty, also what should you do when the variables are equal?

Comment: I have figured out the jump() problem, but the dx and dy problem remains the same

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the part in the input() function marked //Polled input.

When the user presses the KEY_UP key, the first if-condition calls move(DIR.UP). At this point, dy is set to -SPEED. Then the next if-condition checks whether the user is pressing the KEY_DOWN key, sees that he isn't, and calls stop(DIR.DOWN). This sets dy to 0, effectively overwriting the previous call to move(DIR.UP).

The situation with LEFT/RIGHT is identical.

Comment: Ohhhhh and because DOWN and RIGHT are the last if statements for their respective axes they prevent me from moving UP and LEFT because the else statements will nullify dy and dx unless it is DOWN and RIGHT that are called. Thanks!